# What is the best way to display the details of the highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I would like to know what is the right way, I was asked to present the information about the artist who died the oldest.

```
FROM ListOfArtists
WHERE (DateDeceased - DateofBirth) = (SELECT 
            MAX(DateDeceased - DateofBirth)
        FROM ListOfArtists);
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM ListOfArtists
ORDER BY (DateDeceased - DateofBirth) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I would like to know what is the right way* so which one gives you the expected result when you try it?

Comment: The expected result is to only introduce the oldest artist
like this:
ArtistID LastName FirstName Nationality DateDeceased DateOfBirth
5         Chagall          Marc         French         1985         1887

Comment: they do two different things; one reports only 1 result, and one reports all artists with the highest value.   which do you want?   but that is *not* how you get the difference between two dates in mysql; are these just years?

Comment: They both give me the same result, of the oldest artist

Comment: They both give you the same results because you just happened to have one artist of that particular age. But if you had two artists who had lived 98 years and that represented the maximum longevity, you would get two different results from the two queries.

Comment: got it! Thanks!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness the SQL Standard defines the clause `FETCH FIRST n ROWS [WITH TIES]` as an alternative for `LIMIT`. This clause is not implemented in MySQL, however. If it were, then the `WITH TIES` section would produce all the artists with the same age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologise if I have completely over-thought this but I could not resist pointing this out.

Your first comment suggests you are storing just year of birth and death -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Botticelli | Sandro | Italian | 1510 | 1445 |
| 2 | Da Vinci | Leonardo | Italian | 1519 | 1452 |
| 3 | Buonarroti | Michelangelo | Italian | 1564 | 1475 |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986 | 1888 |
| 5 | Chagall | Marc | French | 1985 | 1887 |

Your first query -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ListOfArtists
WHERE (DateDeceased - DateofBirth) = (SELECT 
            MAX(DateDeceased - DateofBirth)
        FROM ListOfArtists);
```

returns -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986 | 1888 |
| 5 | Chagall | Marc | French | 1985 | 1887 |

Your second query -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ListOfArtists
ORDER BY (DateDeceased - DateofBirth) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

returns -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Chagall | Marc | French | 1985 | 1887 |

Now consider the following version of your table but storing complete dates for birth and death -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Botticelli | Sandro | Italian | 1510-05-17 | 1445-01-01 |
| 2 | Da Vinci | Leonardo | Italian | 1519-05-02 | 1452-04-15 |
| 3 | Buonarroti | Michelangelo | Italian | 1564-02-18 | 1475-03-06 |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986-06-11 | 1888-01-01 |
| 5 | Chagall | Marc | French | 1985-03-28 | 1887-07-07 |

Your first query returns -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986-06-11 | 1888-01-01 |

Your second query returns -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986-06-11 | 1888-01-01 |

A better query would be -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ListOfArtists
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DateDeceased, DateofBirth) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

which returns -

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986-06-11 | 1888-01-01 |

The following query illustrates the difference between the two -

```sql
SELECT *, YEAR(DateDeceased) YearDied, YEAR(DateofBirth) YearBorn, (DateDeceased - DateofBirth), DATEDIFF(DateDeceased, DateofBirth) DaysOld, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DateDeceased, DateofBirth) / 365.25) YearsOld
FROM ListOfArtists;
```

| ArtistID | LastName | FirstName | Nationality | DateDeceased | DateOfBirth | YearDied | YearBorn | (DateDeceased - DateofBirth) | DaysOld | YearsOld |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Botticelli | Sandro | Italian | 1510-05-17 | 1445-01-01 | 1510 | 1445 | 650416 | 23876 | 65 |
| 2 | Da Vinci | Leonardo | Italian | 1519-05-02 | 1452-04-15 | 1519 | 1452 | 670087 | 24487 | 67 |
| 3 | Buonarroti | Michelangelo | Italian | 1564-02-18 | 1475-03-06 | 1564 | 1475 | 889912 | 32490 | 88 |
| 4 | Bonestell | Chesley | American | 1986-06-11 | 1888-01-01 | 1986 | 1888 | 980510 | 35955 | 98 |
| 5 | Chagall | Marc | French | 1985-03-28 | 1887-07-07 | 1985 | 1887 | 979621 | 35693 | 97 |

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ace89f/5)